# Python stackplot anomaly

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I have a stackplot in Excel as shown below. I'm trying to generate the same plot using Python.

[image]

My code for the same is below.

```
x = ['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5']
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e']
sns.set(font_scale = 1.25)
plt.stackplot(x,gA,gB,gC,gD,gE,labels=labels) #gA,...,gE stores the percentage values
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.title('Reason')
plt.show()
```

A sample y - `gB` looks like below

```
+---+--------+
|   | Reason |
+---+--------+
| a |      4 |
| b |     32 |
| c |      4 |
| d |     56 |
| e |      4 |
+---+--------+
```

I get a really strange plot when I run this.

[image]

What am I missing out?

Comment: Your question is not [replicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Why don't you share `gA,gB...`?

Comment: Why not use pandas `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Please feel free to use gB for all other g's for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @cs95: I want an area chart. the stacked bar won't give continuity

Comment: Ah, meant [`plot.area(stacked=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.area.html)

Comment: @cs95: I think this'd work. I'll try this. If you can do with the stackplot, let me know.

Comment: I would but I don't have your data, unfortunately.

Comment: @cs95: What other data do you need?

Comment: Preferably gA-gE?

Comment: As I mentioned above, please use gB for all gA-gE.

Comment: With the `gB` provided, the 2nd picture is correct for stack plot. The first plot is relative (all capped at 100%). Is that what you want? If so, @cs95's area plot is the answer.